# WooCommerce Subscriptions: how to determine the last correctly paid order for a given subscription

Tags: woocommerce-subscriptions

Is there any already-programmed method to get the last correctly-paid order for a given subscription?

`$subscription->get_last_order()` will return the last associated order, no matter if that order involved a correct-payment or not.

`$subscription->get_related_orders()` will return the whole list of orders, and the list can include pending-payment or failed orders.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you wrap / trigger `$subscription->get_last_order()` with the `woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete` action (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/) you would essentially achieve that objective. That hook fires both for initial subscription orders and renewal orders and will ensure the $last_order is paid for. Something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'set_last_order' );
function set_last_order( $subscription ) {

    $last_order = $subscription->get_last_order( 'all', 'any' );

    // If you want to be able to reference that $last_order at any time
    // then you could just save/update that order ID to post meta so
    // that you can grab it any time outside of the action.

   }
}
```

I know that seems a little clunky, but it's the best way I can think of. The only other option that comes to mind would be to loop through `$subscription->get_related_orders()` checking is_paid() from high IDs to low IDs and grabbing the first one from there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it won't work for already existing subscriptions...